# How to delete index using Spring Data Elasticsearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to delete indices in Elasticseach instance by code instead of native query.
So I want to do this request:

*DELETE /index-name*

```
  public void deleteFoo(){
    DeleteRequest deleteRequest = new DeleteRequest("Foo");
    Request delete = RequestConverters.delete(deleteRequest);
    elasticsearchTemplate.delete(delete);
  }
```

But I get exception
`org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.elasticsearch.core.TimeValue org.elasticsearch.action.delete.DeleteRequest.timeout()'`

What I am doing wrong?

I try to delete it by name, but would be nice to be able to delete all indices by one query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0 this is possible with

```java
elasticsearchTemplate.indexOps(IndexCoordinates.of("indexname")).delete();
```

Comment: Thank you, already found it. Forgot to answer by myself, my bad :)